# Detect the componet on which user clicked

Tags: angular, rxjs, overlay, mouseclick-event

Iam using a custom side panel child component, say child which would be an entrycomponent.now the component is opening correctly but i need to close the panel on clicking anywhere outside the panel ,that is to detect click on parent component.
Also need to show overlay to the parent component once side panel is opened.

I could find a way with hostlisteners for getting click event? Is there an alternative like fromevent of rxjs ? Can we detect the component name or properties on a mouse click ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use the `this` to get the scope object and from the scope object you can identify the property which contains the component information.

Comment: I would create an `OverlayComponent` which would display a transparent `<div>` and listen for clicks, and then emit a *close* event using a shared service. There is also the CDK library for the Material library that I think has some features for doing this sort of thing. https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Answer (score 0):

Yes using [@Hostlistener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) is the way to go, the easiest way would be to simply toggle "hide" on the sidebar if overlay targeted:

**overlay.component.ts:**

```
@HostListener ('click',['$event']) onClick(event: any) {

  this.parent.hideSideBar(); // get reference of component through parent componentFactory as it's an entryComponent
  this.hideOverlay();
}
```